# Composer update - connection timed out

Tags: composer-php

In my composer.json I updated the following line:

```
 "require": {
     "<x>/<y>" : "dev-<newBranch>"
 }
```

When I call `composer update <x>/<y>` I get this error:

> The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out`

The the given URL is accessible from my browser without any problem.

The package and branch are available on packagist.

---

Output `composer update <x>/<y> -vv`

Exception trace:

> () at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php:550
>    Composer\Util\RemoteFilesystem->get() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php:101
>    Composer\Util\RemoteFilesystem->getContents() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php:682
>    Composer\Repository\ComposerRepository->fetchFile() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php:497
>    Composer\Repository\ComposerRepository->loadRootServerFile() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php:276
>    Composer\Repository\ComposerRepository->hasProviders() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php:99
>    Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool->addRepository() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:378
>    Composer\Installer->doInstall() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:228
>    Composer\Installer->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/UpdateCommand.php:162
>    Composer\Command\UpdateCommand->execute() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:241
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:843
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:193
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:254
>    Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:103
>    Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/bin/composer:56
>    require() at /usr/local/bin/composer:24

---

This appeared after calling: `composer clearcache`

Comment: what's the exact output of `composer update <package> -vv` and `echo "$HTTP_PROXY" "$HTTPS_PROXY"`?

Comment: ` echo "$HTTP_PROXY" "$HTTPS_PROXY"` is empty

Comment: There's - probably important - ouput missing at the beginning of the trace - `[..] ()`. Add the full trace including the exception message please.

Comment: Yes, but only this line: `Exception trace:`

Comment: So I guess not important

Comment: What happens if you try to update composer itself with `composer self-update` ?

Comment: what is that supposed to do?

Comment: Similar:   [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                          
  The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out

Answer (score 0):

Without fully understanding it, this solved the issue:
`sudo sh -c "echo 'precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100' >> /etc/gai.conf"`